# WiX - Silent Installation fails to execute custom action

Tags: wix

Our installer (Let us say 'X') has fllowing custom action which will uninstall some other product (Let us say Y) after the installation of X is completed

CustomAction Id="RemoveProductY" ExeCommand="**msiexec /quiet /x [PRODUCTCODEOFPRODY]**" Directory="TARGETDIR" Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="no" Execute ="commit"

It work perfectly when I install it normally but fails only when I install it silently.

Works : msiexec /i X.msi

Fails : msiexec **/qn** /i X.msi

Please help me with this

Comment: You find out more details about the error looking at logs.

msiexec /l*v log.txt /quiet /x [PRODUCTCODEOFPRODY]

Comment: I tried it but no log has been generated. That is why I doubt that the custom action itself is getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple way to uninstall other products during installing.

Use Upgrade table, but there you specify Upgrade Code instead of Product Code.

E.g.

```
<Upgrade Id="{7F034BD8-2C57-437A-B528-F2554A095CF4}">
  <UpgradeVersion Property="X_PRODUCT_INSTALLED" Maximum="2.0.0" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
</Upgrade>
```

The product with this upgrade code and version <= 2.0.0 will be uninstalled during installation of your one.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the repsonse but I am not looking for upgrading my own product of different version. The product thatI am trying to uninstall is different all together. I know the product code of this prodct Y and I have to uninstall it. Also I have to do it conditionally. ANy help??

Comment: It does not matter if it is yours or not. You can uninstall a lot of other products in this way. Its upgrade code you can find out using Orca e.g.

Comment: I completely aagree with you. But here the context is different. I have to uninstall it conditionally, it should be unistalled only if it passes a condition. This is the reason I am trying to achieve it using custom action. I dont think I can upgrade anything  conditionally. Please correct me If I am wrong